# Cordova Telemetry, what is it and why use it?

Tags: cordova

started a project with plain Cordova. This message keeps turning up:

```
You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
```

Did a short search on this, but find mostly error messages. Can some one enlighten me on what this **Cordova Telemetry** is and what is its use?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Cordova telemetry is a part of the `cordova cli` and collects data about your usage of it. From the [Apache Cordova CLI Privacy Policy](https://cordova.apache.org/privacy/):

- IP address
- OS type and version
- Node version
- Cordova version
- Commands executed, time of execution and status (success/failure)

You can turn on/off from the cordova cli ([cli reference](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/index.html#cordova-telemetry-command)) by:

```
cordova telemetry on
cordova telemetry off
```

Answer (score 14):

cordova telemetry collects developer data of the usage of cordova for the cordova dev-team. The data is shown here:

https://datastudio.google.com/#/org//reporting/0B-Ja5cNOX_XLTElHdWd4V2NUem8/page/xEE

It is NOT collecting user data, just developer data, like which version of cordova you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the tool which anonymously report usage statistics to improve your application over time. You can simply turn it on by typing

```
cordova telemetry on
```

from the Cordova-cli.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the Capacitor CLI run the caommand

```
npx cordova telemetry on
```

Answer (score -1):

It will collects the user information related system and cordova
you can remove this by using

```
cordova telemetry on
```

Thank You