# VS2017 apache cordova Run on desktop

Tags: javascript, cordova

When i try to run my test application in my desktop i am getting below error

**You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.**

Please advice me on same

Comment: Try run: cordova telemetry on

Comment: You've posted what you need to do. What is your actual problem?

Comment: in run command i tried that too but it says cordova is not recognized internal or external commad

Comment: Where did you run it?

Comment: i am new to vs2017 apache cordova ...just i am trying to build my test application, i have tested in android with simulate with browser option i am able to view my application....same when i try to run it my desktop i.e instead of android i choose windows x64

Comment: i ran it on commad prompt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cordova Telemetry, what is it and why use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41225340/cordova-telemetry-what-is-it-and-why-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

cordova telemetry collects developer data of the usage of cordova for the cordova dev-team.

You can turn on/off from the cordova cli by:

```
cordova telemetry on
cordova telemetry off
```