# Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable in Ubuntu

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

```
You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
(node:5862) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
```

I faced this issue when  I try to  build in Ionic . 
this  from  my  `~/.bashrc`

```
  export HOME=home/fabrica
  export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
  export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
  export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
  export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools:$PATH
```

> $ echo  $PATH

will show this

```
home/fabrica/Android/Sdk/build-tools:home/fabrica/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:home/fabrica/Android/Sdk/tools:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/fabrica//Android/Sdk/tools:/home/fabrica//Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/fabrica///Android/Sdk/tools:/home/fabrica///Android/Sdk/platform-tools
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cordova Telemetry, what is it and why use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41225340/cordova-telemetry-what-is-it-and-why-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can remove warning that is coming on first line of error about telemetry

cordova telemetry collects developer data of the usage of cordova for the cordova dev-team.

You can turn on/off from the cordova cli [(cli reference)](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/index.html#cordova-telemetry-command) by:

```
cordova telemetry on
cordova telemetry off
```