# Unable to install the Ionic app in mobile

Tags: android-studio, sdk, ionic2

I have created a simple ionic app and want to install in phone and when i run the command ionic cordova run android it showing me that its failed and getting error as follow.

```
You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\saif.d\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 12.0.2
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

    cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

I am not understanding what problem exactly with android studio and sdk.

Any resolution on this issue id greatly appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: uninstall jdk and install JDK 8

Answer (score 0):

You can simply turn on/off from the cordova cli:-

```
 cordova telemetry on
 cordova telemetry off
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41226048/6080730